# calling created javascript function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to call created JavaScript function in jQuery. I want to trigger the function when its `div` is with 'sample' class.I tried to append class in click event.

My script function worked well when I called in JavaScript. But need to call it in jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#digital-services').click(function() {
    $('#second-menu').addClass('sample');
  });
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var menu = $('.sample');
  console.log(menu.length);
  if (menu.length == 1) {
    var y = setInterval(counter, 10); //calling in jquery not working
  }
});
var y = setInterval(counter, 10); //working
var x = 0;

function counter() {
  if (x < 11) {
    document.getElementById('counter1').innerHTML = x;
  }
  if (x < 601) {
    document.getElementById('counter2').innerHTML = x;
  }
  if (x < 31) {
    document.getElementById('count3').innerHTML = x;
  }
  if (x < 7) {
    document.getElementById('counter4').innerHTML = x;
  }
  if (++x == 601)
    clearInterval(y);
  console.log('counter log');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="digital-services" href="#second-menu">Digital Services</a>
<div class="container" id="second-menu">
  <div class="col-sm-3 digital-services-content">
    <p id="counter1" class="counter1 counting">10</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 digital-services-content">
    <p id="counter2" class="counting">600</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 digital-services-content">
    <p id="count3" class="counter3 counting">30</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 digital-services-content">
    <p id="counter4" class="counter4 counting">6</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have used id `#second-menu` in jquery but I can not see this id in your HTML code ?

Comment: JQuery is OK, but double check ` if (menu.length == 1)`, this one is preventing invocation of your code.

Comment: You're declaring the `y` variable inside the scroll callback. Scope means it's not accessible outside that callback.

Comment: its is working in javascript but not in jquery

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/qd7dmcyd/1/

Comment: for each click I have to call the function

Comment: i think you meant to use trigger("click") of jquery and check with if condition hasClass of jquery.